# Retrieve dictionary from dictionary swift

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, nsdictionary

I am converting objective c code in swift.

I am getting data from server which has a dictionaries in a dictionaries.
i am  getting key value string but cannot get dictionary.

example data:

```
data =         {
            caption = hello;
            image =             {
                a = "https://www.google.com/1024x1024";
                b = "https://www.google.com/640x640";
                c = "https://www.google.com/480x480";
                d = "https://www.google.com/";

            };
        };
```

i can get caption

```
let dataDict = (mainDict[data] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)!

Obj.caption=String(dataDict["caption"]!)  //getting hello

Obj.imageDictionary = (dataDict["image"] as? Dictionary<String,String>)! //getting 0 key value pairs
```

initialised imageDictionary  as

```
var imageDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

please suggest how to get the image dictionary, I want this dictionary to store in imageDictionary object.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the console log for simply `print(dataDict["image"])` without any cast.

Comment: Your spacing is... artistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let data : [String : Any] = ["caption" : "hello",
                             "image" :["a" : "https://www.google.com/1024x1024",
                      "b" : "https://www.google.com/640x640",
                      "c" : "https://www.google.com/480x480",
                      "d" : "https://www.google.com/",
    ]
]

let caption = data["caption"] as! String
let imageDictionary = data["image"] as! [String : String]
```

In `imageDictionary`, I am getting:

```
["b": "https://www.google.com/640x640", "a": "https://www.google.com/1024x1024", "d": "https://www.google.com/", "c": "https://www.google.com/480x480"]
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: hey thanks for answer but in debug left console check imageDictionary is showing 0 key value pairs

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the code and output. Please have a look. Also in debug left console it sometimes show 0 key/value pairs for dictionary. Try printing the object.